# Java - DriverManager.getConnection Access

Tags: java, connection, odbc, ms-access-2007

i have the following code to test a link to a access database on a new server, everything works with the existing server and i am able to access the folder. !if.exists returns true and i can open the data base using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run......... + f); so i know it can see the database. im unable to get a reason for the fail but its 100% failing at Connection conn = de.....

can anyone help me.

running gives following output - Java result: -1073741811

```
package testing;

import connections.LocalProperties;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File f = new File("\\\\***\\***\\****\\***.accdb");


            if (!f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("file does not exist" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("file does exist" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + f.getAbsolutePath();

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String m_URLString = url;
            String m_UserName = System.getProperty("user.name");
            String m_Password = "*******";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(m_URLString, m_UserName, m_Password);
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When running i get the following popups:
Java.exe
If you were in the middle of something, the information might be lost, for more information click here

Error signature

App name:java.exe appver 7.0.30.5 modname:msvcr80.dll

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line-

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

Comment: I did originally have that but it works with or without on the existing database/server. Does not work with or without on the new.

Comment: cant, it says i need 15 reputation. this is my first post. sorry